# Can you increase vibrator strength on android devices?

Tags: android, vibration

Is it possible to increase the strength of the alarm vibration?

Comment: what is the purpose? ;-) (just curious)

Comment: there's an app Dildroid that does exactly that ;-)

Comment: haha thanks but it's not for a dildo :p, when I connect the phone with usb the phone vibrates much stronger than when I use it in my app

Comment: If you replace the motor by a more powerful one...
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykpa5r1bWeE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

apparently not,

under android.os.Vibrator, you can set the pattern as well as the duration

```
vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)

vibrate(long milliseconds)
```

my guess is that different patterns can be used to "simulate" a stronger vibrate. (on,off,on,off) rather than (on, off, off, off, on).

also a disharmonious pattern may be more effective than a pattern with a fixed rhythm.

Comment: Nice answer! I didn't think about patterns before for vibra. +1

Answer (score 3):

The [Vibrator Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) does not allow for this, you can only set the duration.

Answer (score 0):

from API 26 onwards, you can change the strength by setting the amplitude of  VibrationEffect

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect.html

simply create 
    VibrationEffect effect  = VibrationEffect.createOneShot (  milliseconds,    amplitude);

and then set the effect in the vibrator instance.

```
vibrator.vibrate(effect);
```

more details here

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate(android.os.VibrationEffect)