# Vibrator In Android, Stopping when the app exits

Tags: android, android-vibration

I am basically developing an Applicatin which requires the App to Vibrate just before it closes down.

Now when I call the vibrator.vibrate() function and then call the finish() function, the Vibration is stopped and the app is exited, before the Vibration completes.

I want the app to wait until the vibration gets over and then exit!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you sure the vibration duration is as long as you think it is? I just tested on my phone: `vibrator.vibrate(5000); finish();`  My Activity finished and closed immediately, but the vibration did continue for the full 5 seconds.

Comment: hi @MikeM. I tried the same, but it doesn't work for me !
Also, i checked the documentation of the Vibrator Class on developer.android 

it says "If your process exits, any vibration you started will stop."

This is the property that i would like to over-ride

[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need set a duration for vibration for this purpose given links can help you       [Can you increase vibrator strength on android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907219/can-you-increase-vibrator-strength-on-android-devices).
http://techblogon.com/vibrate-android-phone-programmatically/

After setting duration you need set a timer before exiting that equals to the vibration milliseconds :) so your application will exit after vibration period completed.

Comment: Thanks @Nomi This solution kind of worked !!
There are some issue with my UI, but I think I can handle them :)