# Back button stops Vibration android

Tags: android, android-vibration

i'm using the following code to make the device vibrate for 10 seconds on the click of a button however, the vibration can be stopped if the user accidentally presses the hardware back button or the options button. how do i overcome this? thanks in advance

```
mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
mVibrator.vibrate(1000 * 10);// sprint time vibration
```

i have already tried overriding back button but it doesnt help

Tested on **Android 5.0**

Comment: Is vibration really tied to the activity lifecycle? or duration, I would think it would be full duration according to the queue

Comment: I also find that the vibration is not stopped when back button is pressed. Tested with version 22.

Comment: Thats what I thought @Ganesh, Toxic are you sure you're not stopping it anywhere in your code?

Comment: Intresting, I tried this on my Motorola Droid Turbo with 5.1 and I am seeing that the actiity is affecting the duration when hitting the back button.

Comment: what is the good reason behind forcing the device to vibrate for 10 seconds, *even when the user tries to leave the app*?

Comment: alarms would be a good example of when the alarm should vibrate, but of course that is up to discretion of the user/app behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Override OnBackPressed and remove the super.onBackPressed this will disable hardware back press button ...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: i have already tried overriding back button but it doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the documentation say:

```
If your process exits, any vibration you started will stop.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

There seems to be a way to handle this behavior from the perspective of an activity if you do this:

onCreate()-----

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
((Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(10 * 1000);
finish();
```

It seems that you ignore the above condition if you finish the activity after vibrating, also seems that doing this from a service results in the same thing as well (cancels when you leave the activity)

Kudos to:

[Vibrator In Android, Stopping when the app exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320398/vibrator-in-android-stopping-when-the-app-exits)